# Browser downloads the file instead of showing html

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, mern

I have developed MERN app in my local system. I am trying to host it AWS-EC2 (Free Tier).
Never thought deploying would be so painful.(Well, i am beginner to Node. Earlier i have worked with php. I found it easier to integrate)

[I referred this article](https://medium.com/cs-note/setup-node-and-express-on-aws-ec2-windows-7-8cb499ab14eb) to install Node and Express. Node is successfully installed. I created sample file 'test.js' with following code:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var port = 9000;
    http.createServer(function(req,res){ 
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'test/plain'});
    res.end('Hello world!\n');
    }).listen(port);
    console.log('Listening on port',port);
```

After executing

> node test.js

the browser downloads a file with no extension. Opened in editor and it has 'Hello World' in it. Nothing else. I am pretty sure i have followed all steps properly. But still i ended up 'Downloading the file'
Can anyone help me with this issue?

BONUS QUESTION : How do i deploy MERN app in AWS EC2?

Have a nice day
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (you forgot to add the listen callback, and a typo in content type):

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 9000;
http.createServer(function(req,res){ 
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world!\n');
}).listen(port, err => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Listening on port',port);
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) solved my problem. Next time i shall use my brain before copy-paste :p

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate content type for your html page.

```
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
```

For a viewable html code, `text/html` should be set as content type instead of `test/plain`.